# How to display code if is the shop plage display

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to output a html code after page check

I try to use `is_page()` function

```
<?php
    if (is_page( '5873' )) { ?>
    <div class="info_tour-categoria"><?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?></div>
    <?php }
            else {
                //...
            }
     ?>
```

If i put an echo in the else section, this will be show in all categories pages, include the SHOP page, but the if doesn't output nothing...

Comment: Where do you want to display the categories exactly, is it on a specific product by ID?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `title` or `slug` and see if that makes any difference:

```
<?php if (is_page( 'your-page-slug' )) : ?>
<div class="info_tour-categoria"><?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
// your other code
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I answer to your comment

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if (is_page( 'shop' )) : ?>
<div class="info_tour-categoria"><?php echo $product->get_categories(); ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
// your other code
<?php endif; ?>
```

This is the code with your changes, and this is the result in the shop page

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDAUg.png)